# How to weather seal uneven garage door?

Tags: heating, garage, sealing, weatherstripping

This is the garage door (at my business) and it is not seal from outside. No weather strip present.

[image]

**How do I suppose to seal it with this weather strip though?** There will be gaps due to the pattern of the garage door surface.

[image]

Also you see a bunch of rubber falling apart. **What are those? Do I suppose to fix them or doesn't matter?**

Comment: Think you might need to fill in those depressions at the edges so the door presents a flat edge for weather stripping.

Comment: What do people usually fill them with? It's a metal door.

Comment: I am not sure.  Would think something rigid like plastic/wood/hard foam/rubber.  Probably need to be glued or screwed on.  Thickness would need to match the high parts.  Most weather stripping is made to seal two not quite prefect flat surfaces.  Maybe some short pieces of metal flashing.